# Predictions using Logistic Regression in Pytorch return infinity

Tags: pytorch

I started watching a tutorial on PyTorch and I am learning the concept of logistic regression.

I tried it using some stock data that I had. I have `inputs`, which contains two parameters `trade_quantity` and `trade_value`, and `targets` which has the corresponding stock price.

```
inputs = torch.tensor([[182723838.00, 2375432.00],
                       [185968153.00, 2415558.00],
                       [181970093.00, 2369140.00],
                       [221676832.00, 2811589.00],
                       [339785916.00, 4291782.00],
                       [225855390.00, 2821301.00],
                       [151430199.00, 1889032.00],
                       [122645372.00, 1552998.00],
                       [129015052.00, 1617158.00],
                       [121207837.00, 1532166.00],
                       [139554705.00, 1789392.00]])

targets = torch.tensor([[76.90],
                        [76.90],
                        [76.90],
                        [80.70],
                        [78.95],
                        [79.60],
                        [80.05],
                        [78.90],
                        [79.40],
                        [78.95],
                        [77.80]])
```

I defined the model function, the loss as the mean square error, and tried to run it a few times to get some predictions. Here's the code:

```
def model(x):
    return x @ w.t() + b

def mse(t1, t2):
    diff = t1 - t2
    return torch.sum(diff * diff) / diff.numel()

preds = model(inputs)
loss = mse(preds, targets)
loss.backward()
with torch.no_grad():
    w -= w.grad * 1e-5
    b -= b.grad * 1e-5
    w.grad.zero_()
    b.grad.zero_()
```

I am using Jupyter for this and ran the last part of the code a few times, after which the predictions come as:

```
tensor([[inf],
        [inf],
        [inf],
        [inf],
        [inf],
        [inf],
        [inf],
        [inf],
        [inf],
        [inf],
        [inf]], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
```

If I run it for a few more times the predictions become `nan`. Can you please tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, this looks more like linear regression than logistic regression. You are trying to fit a linear model onto your data. It's different to a binary classification task where you would need to use a special kind of activation function (a [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) for instance) so that the output is either `0` or `1`.

In this particular instance you want to solve a 2D linear problem given input `x` of shape `(batch, x1, x2)` (where `x1` is `trade_quantity` and `x2` is `trade_value`) and target `(batch, y)` (`y` being the `stock_price`).

So the objective is to find the best `w` and `b` matrices (weight matrix and bias column) so that `x@w + b` is the closest to `y` as possible, *according to your criterion, the mean square error*.

---

I would recommend normalizing your data so it stays in a `[0, 1]` range. You can do so by measuring the *mean* and *standard deviation* of `inputs` and `targets`.

```
inputs_min, inputs_max = inputs.min(axis=0).values, inputs.max(axis=0).values
targets_min, targets_max = targets.min(axis=0).values, targets.max(axis=0).values
```

Then applying the transformation:

```
x = (inputs - inputs_min)/(inputs_max - inputs_min)
y = (targets - targets_min)/(targets_max - targets_min)
```

Try changing your learning rate and have it run for multiple epochs.

```
lr = 1e-2
for epochs in range(100):
    preds = model(x)
    loss = mse(preds, y)
    loss.backward()
    with torch.no_grad():
        w -= lr*w.grad
        b -= lr*b.grad
        w.grad.zero_()
        b.grad.zero_()
```

I use a `(1, 2)` randomly initialized matrix for `w` (and a `(1,)` matrix for `b`):

```
w = torch.rand(1, 2)
w.requires_grad = True
b = torch.rand(1)
b.requires_grad = True
```

And got the following train loss over *100* epochs:

[image]

To find the right hyperparameters, it's better to have a validation set. This set will get normalized with the *mean* and *std* from the train set. It will be used to evaluate the performances at the end of each epoch on data that is 'unknown' to the model. Same goes for your test set, if you have one.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain so wonderfully. Just one small doubt: Is the normalizing process used when dealing with large numbers or is it just best to use it wherever you can?

Comment: And Just one more thing : When I print the preds, they are less than 1, which is no where close to the targets??

Comment: It helps with training the model's parameters. 
It's generally a good idea (when working with a MLP - *multi-layer perceptron*) when dealing with very different feature ranges (here `trade_quantity` is around 80x bigger than `trade_value`). This will avoid giving too much precedence over one feature (`trade_quantity`) or the other (`trade_value`). 
`preds` are lower than `1` because we are fitting on normalized values (`y`). In order to get the *real* predictions you just have to unnormalize it: `preds*(targets_max - targets_min) + targets_min`. 
Glad it helped! ;)